# How to make a queue in php to manage requests?

Tags: php, request, queue

I have an ajax form in my site that send many request to this php file fo get some information.

How to make a queue in this php file to process just 1 request per second and not more?

php file:

```
<?php
function isJson ($str) {
    json_decode($str);
    return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}
$service_url = 'https://example.com/api-local-json.php?cmd=whois&domain='.$_GET['domain'];
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 29);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
if(!$curl_response){
    echo '{"result": "error"}';
}
curl_close($curl);
if (isJson($curl_response)) {
    echo $curl_response;
} else {
    echo '{"result": "error"}';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be thought of as the concept of throttling in php. You can simply choose to delay between successive requests .
 **`Like sleep(5);`** this can be used once you make a request and then it will wait for 5 seconds .

OR You can implement slack , gearmean , or rabbitmq that provides these facilities of queuing , message broking and worker handling .

Comment: Thank you, using of  sleep(); is an good idea. but when I using that in first line (and other lines) of my php script it just make a delay in first request and all other requests process together and make server load again.

Comment: use this after one complete request as in for instance you can use it like do while loop at first it will run with out sleep () and from then starting from 2nd request it will be having sleep().

Comment: Ok, but in this case I want to make the queue for all users that using my webpage with multi ip addresses and... to avoid server load. I thing it may need a database queue or something like that. But I don't know how to do that. Do you have any idea dude?

Comment: Yeah, You would need to implement some queuing mechanism like gearman , rabbitmq for this! do try any of these .